# Dimension of the set of affine continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, affine-geometry

I came across the following statement while reading a paper.

Suppose $a=x_0 < x_1<...<x_{n-1}<x_n=b$. Then, the vector space of continuous functions on $(a,b)$ that are affine on each interval $[x_i , x_{i+1}],$ for $i=0,1,...,n-1$, has dimension $n+1$.

I'm not able to see why the dimension is $n+1$. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each such function $f$, you have $n+1$ choices: the values that $f$ takes at $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$. So, the dimension is $n+1$.

To be more precise: if $a_k=f(x_k)$ ($k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$), then $f$ is completely determined. It is the only function from $[a,b]$ into $\Bbb R$ such that its restriction to $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ is defined by$$f(x)=a_{k-1}+\frac{x-x_{k-1}}{x_k-x_{k-1}}(a_k-a_{k-1}).$$If, for each $j\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, you define $f_j\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ as the only function whose restriction to each interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ is affine, such that $f_j(x_j)=1$ and that $f_j(x_k)=0$ if $k\ne j$, then the set $\{f_0,f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ will be a basis of your space.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks. One more question. If we change the lattice structure, say , the vector space of continuous (at all the integer points on $[a,b]$), then, does the same result hold?. It seems it does.

Note: In this case, we are talking about functions that are discretely affine by parts.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question. That is, I don't understand which space is the new space.

Comment: Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and there exist integer points $y_1,y_2,...,y_{n-1}$ such that $a=y_0 < y_1<...<y_{n-1}<y_n=b$.

Now, does the same result hold for the space of continuous (at integer points) functions on $[a,b]$ that are affine by parts on $[y_i, y_{i+1}].$

Comment: Yes, it holds.${}$

Comment: I know it's been almost two weeks since I posted this; so apologize for bringing this up again. But, I've this question about the discrete case.

Suppose we consider the space of all discrete affine functions on $[0,2]$ (which means we only have 3 points $0,1$ and $2$). Now, the question is what would be the dimension of this space? In the continuous case, the answer would be $2$ because we can describe any affine function on $[0,2]$ using $2$ functions like you've explained.

Comment: But, the same will not be applicable to the discrete case. The reason is , now, we can define point masses at $0,1$ and $2$ to be our basis functions. So, any affine function on this interval can be written in terms of them.

Am I missing something here?.

Comment: What is a discrete affine function?

Comment: By discrete affine , I meant an affine function defined at integer points. For ex: $f(x) = x$ on $\{0,1,2\}$. So basically, it is the restriction of any affine function on $\mathbb{R}$ to integer points.

Comment: But then the dimension of that space is equal to the number of integer points. For instance, the dimension of the space of all functions from $\{0,1,2\}$ into $\Bbb R$ is $3$. A basis of this space is $\{f_0,f_1,f_2\}$ with$$f_i(j)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }i=j\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yeah exactly what I thought.